# Specifying Custom Serializer for MemberMap in MongoDB - One Instance or Many?

Tags: mongodb, serialization, mongodb-.net-driver

In specifying custom serialization for individual properties, I am currently using a separate instance for each case:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyClass>(map =>
{
    map.AutoMap();
    map.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);
    map.MapProperty(p=>Property1).SetSerializer(new MyCustomSerializer());
    map.MapProperty(p=>Property2).SetSerializer(new MyCustomSerializer());
}
```

Can I specify the same instance in both cases?

```
var ser = new MyCustomSerializer();
map.MapProperty(p=>Property1).SetSerializer(ser);
map.MapProperty(p=>Property2).SetSerializer(ser);
```

I *suspect* that this is ok because one could use

```
[BsonSerializer(typeof(MyCustomSerializer))]
public string Property1 { get; set; }
[BsonSerializer(typeof(MyCustomSerializer))]
public string Property2 { get; set; }
```

and this is not using *any* instances

Answer (score 1):

Since it's your custom serializer, it's up to you to ensure that there isn't any state being stored at the instance level. From the driver's perspective, we don't care.

FYI: when you use the attribute form, we create 2 seperate instances of the serializer using the default ctor. So your code version would be different, although it doesn't matter as long as your serializer plays nice.

Comment: Ok, that's great. We might wind up using the same serializer for properties in several classes, and might want one instance per class.